# "Expiry date" Vs. "Expiration date"

Tags: difference

Can I expiry date about foods? I was told that the difference between expiry date and expiration date, is that the last is for food, and expiry date is for contracts or agreements. Not sure if this information is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[british-english](/questions/tagged/british-english)

I would consider expiry date and expiration date to be synonyms, but "expiry date" to be more common.  This [Ngrams graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=expiry%20date%2Cexpiration%20date&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=29&smoothing=3) gives some support to that, but I note that "expiration date" is becoming more common.

For food, the phrases "best before" date, and "use by" date are more correctly used (these are printed on perishable food, with "use by" being a safety instruction and "best before" quality information) But "expiry date" would be understood if applied to food.  Historically "Sell by date" also has a similar meaning, and may be applied metaphorically.

Contracts have an expiry or expiration date.  I think this is dialect dependent, and different terms are used in America.

Comment: We don't use generally *expiry* in American English (although we would understand it).

Comment: @PeterShor Do you mean Americans don't use "expiry" for food, or not for contracts, or not at all?

Comment: @gotube: We certainly don't use it for food. Lawyers might use it; the [American Heritage Dictionary](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=expiry) defines it as "An expiration, especially of a contract or an agreement." But it's not a usage that a typical American runs into very often.

Comment: @PeterShor Interesting. Here in Canada my guess is the two are about the same, which figures if we're culturally between the US and the UK.